# Convert date from excel file to pandas

Tags: excel, pandas, datetime

I'm importing excel file, where the 'Date' column has different ways of writing:

```
      Date
13/03/2017
13/03/2017
13/03/2017
13/03/2017
   10/3/17
   10/3/17
    9/3/17
    9/3/17
    9/3/17
    9/3/17
```

Importing to pandas:

```
df = pd.read_excel('data_excel.xls')
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
```

results in:

```
                     Date
               13/03/2017
64             13/03/2017
65             13/03/2017
66             13/03/2017
67    2017-10-03 00:00:00
68    2017-10-03 00:00:00
69    2017-09-03 00:00:00
70    2017-09-03 00:00:00
71    2017-09-03 00:00:00
72    2017-09-03 00:00:00
```

Which means, pandas did not parse properly date and time:

```
10/3/17 -> 2017-10-03
```

when I tried to specify the format:

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%d%m%Y')
```

got the error:

```
ValueError: time data u'13/03/2017' does not match format '%d%m%Y' (match)
```

**Question:**

How to import properly date and times from the excel file to pandas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

New answer:

Actually `pd.to_datetime` has a `dayfirst` keyword argument that is useful here:

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date,dayfirst=True)
```

Result:

```
>>> df.Date
0   2017-03-13
1   2017-03-13
2   2017-03-13
3   2017-03-13
4   2017-03-10
5   2017-03-10
6   2017-03-09
7   2017-03-09
8   2017-03-09
9   2017-03-09
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

---

Old answer:

Use the third-party module [`dateutil`](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) which can handle these kinds of variations. It has a `dayfirst` keyword argument that is useful here:

```
import dateutil

df = pd.read_excel('data_excel.xls')
df.Date = df.Date.apply(lambda x: dateutil.parser.parse(x,dayfirst=True))
```

Result:

```
>>> df.Date
0   2017-03-13
1   2017-03-13
2   2017-03-13
3   2017-03-13
4   2017-03-10
5   2017-03-10
6   2017-03-09
7   2017-03-09
8   2017-03-09
9   2017-03-09
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: amazing! thanks for pointing to 'dayfirst=True' option. I converted to CSV file, with small tweaks solved the problem, but this solution is far robust.