# Pandas Python - Trailing timestamp removal

Tags: python, pandas, csv, xlsx

I'm new to Pandas and Python and ran into an issue. The code works "almost" as expected. When converting from xlsx to csv the date timestamp is a follows **06/12/2018 0:00**. I'm wanting to remove the **'0:00'** time portion. How can this be done? Below is a snapshot of the data (which are separate columns in a .csv file. Also, below is the code. Thanks.

XOM | 86547218 | 6 |Tony |Jonny |**8/8/2017 0:00** |543267873 | 754732 |**6/14/2012 0:00**| **8/8/2017 0:00** |100 |**6/14/2017 0:00**

```
   import pandas as pd

   df = pd.read_excel('.xlsx', header=None)
   df.to_csv('.csv', header=None, date_format = '%m/%d/%Y', index=False)
```

Additionally, the conversion works from .xlsx to .csv the only issue I am having is with the dates which are in multiple columns and in a vastly large data set. Thanks.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43023226/convert-date-from-excel-file-to-pandas?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a series `date` which contains your `datetime` values, you can convert to a string in your desired format *before* exporting to CSV:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('now', periods=4, freq='15D')})

df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

print(df)

#          date
# 0  04/16/2018
# 1  05/01/2018
# 2  05/16/2018
# 3  05/31/2018
```

Comment: How would this work with multiple columns having a vast amount of dates? This seems to limit the amount. I might be wrong as I am new to pandas and python. Thanks. @jpp

Comment: @New_to_Python, I'm not sure what you mean, you can loop through as many columns as you like, e.g. `for col in ['date1', 'date2', 'date3']: df[col] = .....`. Have you tested performance to see if this is a problem?

Comment: When integrating your suggestion into my code (shown above) all that is shown in the .csv after conversion from .xlsx is a column of 4 dates. The .xlsx files has multiple columns with different data sets and dates, along with a header.  My original code was able to convert everything over, even the dates, but with the trailing 0:00 which I don't want. Your code works, but it removes all my other data. Any suggestions. Thanks. @jpp

Comment: No idea. You can try **[editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49864359/edit)** your question with some of your data, because I cannot see the problem as you describe it.

Comment: I went ahead and edited my information. Let me know if you can help or additional info is needed. Also, I appreciate you and everyone for taking the time. @jpp